# Delete rows from the second table if the corresponding user is deleted from the first table

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm deleting some rows (users) from a table using the following query

```
DELETE
FROM
    rfs_users
WHERE
    ID > 1 AND user_registered < '2017-05-16 12:09:54' AND user_login NOT IN ('username1', 'username2')
```

I have another table and I also need to delete some rows from it. This table (`rfs_usermeta`) has a different structure and I can't use the same query on it.

In `rfs_users`, one row corresponds to one user. In `rfs_usermeta`, multiple rows corresponds to one user. I could just use

```
DELETE FROM rfs_usermeta WHERE user_id > 1
```

but that would delete almost all rows. I need to delete a user in `rfs_usermeta` if that user is also to be deleted in `rfs_users`.

For example:

```js
// loop rows in rfs_users
for (row in rfs_users) {
    // target specific rows
    if (row.user_id > 1 && row.user_registered < '2017-05-16 12:09:54' && !('username1', 'username2').includes(row.user_login)) {
        // delete matching row
        row.remove()
        // also delete rows from rfs_usermeta
        rfs_usermeta.getRows(row.user_id).remove()
    }
}
```

How do I form this query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does the `usermeta` have a Foreign Key Constraint to the `users` table? If so you can set what happens in the referenced row.

You can automatically remove corresponding rows by adding the foreign key constraint to the `usermeta` like this:

```
ALTER TABLE usermeta ADD CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES users(id) ON DELETE CASCADE;
```

This removes all `usermeta` rows that reference a removed user.

If you do not want to do that you can also add a Trigger to the user table that removes `usermeta` rows.

Hope this helps ;)

Comment: This did the trick. Though, I had to look it up because I'm not really familiar with SQL. [FOREIGN KEY Constraint](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_foreignkey.asp) helped me understand it.

Answer (score 1):

Run this alter.On delete cascade will automatically take care of this.

```
alter table rfs_usermeta modify constraint fk_name foreign key (user_id) references rfs_users (ID) on delete cascade;
```